# How can i compare if last downloaded satellite image and the current downloaded satellite image are identical or not?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With this class i'm trying to make the comparison today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using mws;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DannyGeneral;



namespace General_utility
{


  static  class File_Utility
    {
      static  public bool File_Comparison(string Filename_1, string Filename_2)
        {
            FileInfo fi;
            int i;
           byte[] a,b;
           a=File.ReadAllBytes(Filename_1);
           b=File.ReadAllBytes(Filename_2);
           fi = new FileInfo(a.ToString());
         if (a.Length != b.Length)
         {
             return false;
         }
         else
         {
             for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
             {
                 if (a[i] != b[i])
                     return false;                 
             }
         }
         return true;

        }

    }

}
```

Then i'm using it this way:

```
file_compare = File_Utility.File_Comparison(temp_sat_dir, last_file_satellite);
```

file_compare is a bool
temp_sat_dir is the current downloaded file: C:\Users\temp\satellite.jpg

The file in temp_sat_dir will be allways the same name.

And last_file_satellite is the last file downloaded and that i copied to a new directory: C:\Users\satelliteImages\SatImage000863.gif

Then i decide if to download the next files i need or not. If the first current file is not the same then continue and download the rest of the files but if it's identical don't download the rest:

```
if (file_compare == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            client1.DownloadFile(link, filePath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            DannyGeneral.Logger.Write(e.ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

The first time file_compare was false and it downloaded the file using client1.
All my code is in loop i didn't show it here but it's in a loop and it's downloading each 15 minutes new 9 files.

But the problem is that if i run the program over again or if 15 minutes passed it will keep download the same 9 images.

I need somehow to make it download only if the first file is not the same like the last one.

The problem is that file_compare is false now again. First it downloaded the 9 files now i ran the program again and still it's false. And the images are the same i checked. The file satellite.jpg and SatImage000863.gif are the same so it should doing the break; 
But it dosen't it give false.

Comment: sorry if I'm stating the obvious, but how could `satellite.jpg` and `SatImage000863.gif` be the same? they aren't even the same encoding format.

Comment: Claies about the format you right. But in logic if i downloaded the file satellite.jpg after 15 minutes again and again and nothing changed the satellite.jpg is look the same like the last file on my hard disk SatImage000863.gif then they are the same. And i will change the format it was my mistake for some reason i kept the satellite as jpg and not gif.

Comment: Claies in general i don't want to download each time the same files only new ones. This is a link for example how the satellite image look like: http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201502150945&ir=True

Comment: This is the type of problem that you would need a multi-million research grant and five years of research to find a solution. Don't even think about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you copied the file to "C:\Users\satelliteImages\SatImage000863.gif", you apparently saved it instead of copying. Even if you save it as a .jpg file, it will probably not be identical to the original. Instead of doing an image save, use system.io.file.copy (or move) to copy the original file so it can be compared with the next one downloaded.